# Coefficient of determination in predict()

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I'm trying to valdidate my linear regression model by using the `predict()` function. I use calibration and validation data sets for that. Is there a way to get R^2 as an output for `predict()`? I want to compare it with the summary of my calibration set.

At the moment I don't understand the output of `predict()`.

That's part of my code:

```
model<-lm(y~x, data=daten)
model

model2<-predict(model,daten2)
model2

summary(model)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = daten)

 Residuals:
 Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.0347 -1.4576 -0.7656  1.4046  5.5095 

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -44.03468    7.40057  -5.950 1.58e-05 ***
x             0.39646    0.04928   8.045 3.38e-07 ***
 ---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.728 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.792, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7798 
F-statistic: 64.73 on 1 and 17 DF,  p-value: 3.379e-07

summary(model2)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
4.719  12.820  15.350  15.650  20.180  27.370
```

Comment: What/where is your known response variable? That is, you feed `x` from `dataen2` into a model to obtain predicted `y`. To test how good your model is, you need known `y`s to compare to.

Comment: No, `predict` can't give your R². It gives you predictions.

Comment: How can I validate my regression? By comparing which values?

Comment: You get R^2 from `summary(model)$r.squared`.

Comment: Thanks, by comparing both R^2, how do I know, which model is the best? When they have similar values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RMSE <- function(fitted, true){
  sqrt(mean((fitted - true)^2))
}

R2 <- function(fitted, true){
 1 - (sum((true - fitted)^2)/sum((true - mean(true))^2))
}
```

fitted values are in model2, while true values are probably in responce variable from daten2

```
RMSE(model2, daten2$y)

R2(model2, daten2$y)
```

The point is: to calculate a goodness of fit metric you need to supply the true outcomes along with the predicted values. "predict.lm" just provides the predicted values